# Access hidden column on main view from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main page called `Index` which has a hidden field column named `ApplicationID`. On `Index` I render a partial view called `_Hours`.

Is is possible to access the value of `ApplicationID` on the `Index` view from the `_Hours` partial view?

Comment: access it how?  How I would grab the value would be from javascript but that would reside on the index view.

Comment: Like such: `@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddOperationHour", new { appID = [VALUE_FROM_INDEXVIEW] })`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to build that with jquery

```
//load partial
$('.linkClass').attr("src", "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { appID = "----" })".replace("----", $('.valueClass').val());
```

this will set the source of a link to the url.action using the value from the field based on the class